# Microsoft Azure - obtaining verbose logging for services

Tags: azure, logging

Our entire back-end and front-end architecture lives in Azure.  Recently our clients have been running into connectivity issues all too often, and we are having trouble diagnosing the issue. The standard logging for Azure services seems to leave a lot to be desired.  Our developers are very experienced and feel they could permanently resolve the issues if they had better logging to diagnose.

Without getting into every service we have on Azure, is there an Azure service that we can add that will give us better logging for *all* of our services.  If this doesn't exist, is there at least a better way to get more verbose logging on a by-service basis?

We have no need for fancy graphs and neatly-formatted statistics - we just need verbose logging.

EDIT:
Please if you downvote, Please explain your reasoning, or it offers no help to the community whatsoever.  If you downvote without explaining why, you're taking away from the community in the same exact way in which you perceive the post that you downvoted to be doing. Thank you.

Comment: Mitch, I've done a search for Trace Statements in Azure Services and I get no results.  I'm assuming then that this isn't the actual name of the Azure Service and you're just indicating that we should use trace statements?
  It's hard to tell because your answer is two words with no context. Does it fall under a different name in Azure Services?

Comment: downwoted for caps edit. Not nice.

Comment: @trailmax - well at least you have the you-know-what to say so and identify yourself.  Thank you for that.  I will edit the edit to be more kind.

Comment: Have you tried integration [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)?

Comment: @PeterBons no I haven't   I will read your linked article - thank you.  Do you have any experience with it?  What kind of testimonial could you give if so?

Comment: Yes, we use it a lot. It tracks calls to http dependencies as well, like storage accounts etc. It allows custom metrics/errors as well. Using analysis tools you can see things like error rate, requests per second and performance in a timeline as well.

Comment: @Stpete111 Removed the downvote after removing the caps. Should really pay less attention to minuses.

Comment: @trailmax Noted, and thank you.

Comment: @PeterBons thank you.  We're implementing this today to see if it fits our needs.